# Nokia 640 some Bluetooth files don't show up

Tags: bluetooth, pictures

I have sent about 15 pictures via Bluetooth from my Moto g to my Nokia Lumia 640, all showed up except 4. I cannot find those four in my phone anywhere. They were sent successfully. I just don't understand what is going on with the other 4 pictures. Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
           Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Resend them and search again.
2. If you can't find them, check their format. Is it different from the others? Is their size significant?
3. Download an app called [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL). With this app you can navigate to every folder and file in your mobile phone. If you can't find them using Files they are not in your phone.

[image]